# Deployment of a VS2010 VSTO application via ClickOnce - Not everything is correctly linked

Tags: dll, deployment, vsto, clickonce

Here is my problem. I am trying to deploy a VSTO application in a shared folder.For this purpose, I am using the "Publish" utility of VS2010. However, my VSTO project is using an in-house library to access a given DB (DB.dll). The dll itself relies on  an .xml file where the database configuration is stored. When deploying the application, the xml file is not copied  to the output folder. Also, when launching the application from users PC, the application fails to connect to the db. When using reflexion,to see if the path used to access the db.dll is right, I am redirected to a strange folder inside "App_Data" (but maybe it is normal when ClickOnce deploys the application) but the xml-file is not present in this folder either.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with ClickOnce, your customisation gets 'installed' into the ClickOnce cache in the user's profile folder.  It is said that you can avoid this by adding '|vstolocal' to the AssemblyLocation property you use to attach the customisation to a document, though I'm having trouble myself making this actually work.